# Iterate over two numpy 2d matrices using nditer

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, iterator

I am trying to iterate over two numpy matrices, one of size nx3 and the other of size nx1

I'm trying to get nditer to simultaneously iterate over their rows.

So if we have:

```
y = np.array([   [ 1],
                 [-1],
                 [ 1]   ])
x = np.array([[ 1.3432504 , -1.3311479 ,  1.        ],
             [ 1.8205529 , -0.6346681 ,  1.         ],
             [ 0.98632067, -1.8885762 ,  1.         ]])
```

and i try:

```
for (a,b) in iterator:
   print(a)
   print(b)
```

this should give

```
[1]
[ 1.3432504 , -1.3311479 ,  1.        ]
[-1]
[ 1.8205529 , -0.6346681 ,  1.         ]
[1]
[ 0.98632067, -1.8885762 ,  1.         ]
```

I tried np.nditer with 'external_loop flag', i get the desired output for x but it forces y into bunches of 3 elements when i only want one at a time.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is `iterator`?  `nditer` is not an easy thing to use, and does not offer any performance value when used in Python code.  You need to read the tutorial page all the way through to `cython` example.

Comment: Look at the code for `apply_along_axis`.  It uses `ndindex` to generate indices, and then uses these to iterate over all the array except for one axis.  And look at `ndindex`.  It uses `nditer` with `multi_index`.  I don't know of another `numpy` function that uses the Python API to `nditer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to control the 'depth' of iteration with `nditer`.  For example the simplest case:

```
In [35]: for i,j in np.nditer([y, x]):
    ...:     print(i, j)
    ...:     
1 1.3432504
1 -1.3311479
1 1.0
-1 1.8205529
-1 -0.6346681
-1 1.0
1 0.98632067
1 -1.8885762
1 1.0
```

This creates an `(i,j) pair of values for each broadcastable combination of`y`and`x`.`x`is (3, 3),`y`is (3,1)` to the result is an iteration over (3,3).flat.

(If `x` was `np.arange(n)`, `nditer` would generate all combinations of the (3,1) array with (1,n), ie a (3,n) set.

You can't readily tell `nditer` to iterate just on the rows of `x`.  `external_loop` sort of does it, but isn't predictable.

`ndindex` generates indices for a given depth, but it does so by creating an array of the right shape.

```
In [38]: for i,j in np.ndindex(2,3):
    ...:     print(i,j)
    ...:     
0 0
0 1
0 2
1 0
1 1
1 2
```

Or to iterate on the rows of your 2 arrays:

```
In [39]: for i in np.ndindex(3):
    ...:     print(y[i], x[i,:])
    ...:     
[1] [[ 1.3432504 -1.3311479  1.       ]]
[-1] [[ 1.8205529 -0.6346681  1.       ]]
[1] [[ 0.98632067 -1.8885762   1.        ]]
```

But you could just as well used `for i in range(3):`.

`np.nditer` is, more than anything, a stepping stone for developing `cython` or other `c-api` code.  The c-api version of `nditer` has a lot of power, and relatively good speed.  The python equivalent is not fast nor powerful.

Your comments mention further interface with `apply_along_axis`.  That is written in Python, and uses `ndindex` to generate indices for axes that require iteration.  It may make certain tasks more convenient, but it won't speed up your code.

Comment: This clarifies many things, i should just go on and use some of the simpler stuff such as zip, range or nditer. The idea behind this was to find some sort of zip equivalent for numpy arrays, nditer just isn't that. Thank you for the clear explanations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip()` built-in function:

```
In [22]: for i, j in zip(y, x):
             print(i);print(j)
   ....:     
[1]
[ 1.3432504 -1.3311479  1.       ]
[-1]
[ 1.8205529 -0.6346681  1.       ]
[1]
[ 0.98632067 -1.8885762   1.        ]
```

Comment: i know about zip but i am trying to make this efficient using np.nditer

Comment: If you just want to print the items `nditer` is sort of overkill for this task and `zip` efficient enough.

Comment: it isn't for a print, it is for use with a function taking (a,b) arguments, and i will be using that function with np.apply_along_axis. The goal here is to create the iteration giving both rows and then apply that function along every row for a huge matrix.

Comment: @Roulbacha Well, `apply_along_axis` is already a problem for your newar-C-level  performance flow and the abstraction will ruine the chain. Therefore I think going with `zip` will cause no harm in this case. Nevertheless, you can benchmark both approaches (even with the wrong `nditer` code) just for peace of mind ;).

Comment: zip turns out to be the go-to solution. nditer is just not appropriate.